# string slicing without using a collection type such as .split()

Tags: python-3.x

This function is used to find the minumum of GDP in a text where the GDP is a float, this is then returned to be used as the index of a correlating number in the GDP.txt, I get an Error cannot convert float to string for the line 'if float(value) < float(min_val):' when the code is ran, to fix this issue i added .split() to group the numbers of the GDP together by spaces between two seperate GDPs, however; the project requires that we do not use .split(),  because it creates a list which is a collection type, which is not allowed in the project. Therefore, I am seeking another method to group the numbers together in each GDP to allow me to convert them to a float without creating a collection type such as created with the function .split()

line 9 of the text, which holds the value of GDP from 1978 to 2015 reads:

```
1        Gross domestic product                                A191RL1          3.1         0.2         3.3         5.2         5.6        -0.5        -0.2         5.4         4.6         5.6         3.2        -0.2         2.6        -1.9         4.6         7.3         4.2         3.5         3.5         4.2         3.7         1.9        -0.1         3.6         2.7         4.0         2.7         3.8         4.5         4.5         4.7         4.1         1.0         1.8         2.8         3.8         3.3         2.7         1.8        -0.3        -2.8         2.5         1.6         2.2         1.7         2.4         2.6
```

where the white space between each GDP is 12

```
def find_min_percent(line):
    '''Find the min percent change in the line; return the value and the index.'''
    min_val = 100000
    new_line = ''
    n = 76
    loop_count = 0
    while(True):
        n += 12
        loop_count += 1 
        new_line = line[76:n+12]
        if loop_count == 47:
            break
        for value in new_line.split():
            if value != string.punctuation:
                if float(value) < float(min_val):
                    min_val = value
                    min_val_index = line.find(min_val)
    print(min_val, min_val_index)
    return min_val, min_val_index
```

Comment: please add some sample data from the text file.

Comment: added some, let me know if that helps